# disallow " in input with jquery validation engine

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to disallow the user to enter " in the textbox. For validation i'm using jQuery validation engine. Is there a built-in function that does that, and if there is none, can u please tell me how to write a custom validation rule? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is create your own validation method, using [addMethod](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage).

For your particular case, you'd want to make something like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod('noquote', function(val,el){
  return this.optional(el) || !val.match(/"/);
},'No quotes allowed in this field');
```

And then either set `class="noquote"` on your input, or define it in your rules like so:

```
$('#myForm').validate({
   rules: {
      inputname: {
         noquotes: true,
         required: true
      }
   }
});
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/Ckw5w/

Answer (score 0):

Just use the *.keypress()* function.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ID OF TEXTBOX HERE').keypress(function(e){
        if(e.which==34){
           return false;
        }            
    });
});​
```

I also made a demo for you: http://jsfiddle.net/bHhpW/2/

Hope this helps!

Also go to http://api.jquery.com/keypress/ to learn more about the event (**also has a demo that will give you keycode info!**)

Comment: actually, `$('#NAME OF TEXTBOX HERE')` should be `$('#ID OF TEXTBOX HERE')`. and since we're talking about jquery, it should be `e.which` instead of `e.keyCode`